# One to many relationship failure

Tags: ms-access, one-to-many

I am trying to create a one to many relationship in Access. Here is my challenge:

I have a list of asset managers (the one) in a dedicated table and a list of funds (the many) in another table.

Each asset manager may have more than one fund associated with them, hence I decided to separate the two by creating two tables.

I have the `SponsorID` as my PK in the `asset managers` table and I have the `CounterpartyID` as my PK in the `funds` table.

I added in the `funds` table a field called `SponsorID` to create possibility to link the tables and then I opened the relationship dialog box to constitute the actual link, whereby the field `SponsorID` in the asset managers's table (the one) is linked to the `SponsorID` field in the funds table, which should bring the FK in the funds table.

When I run a query to see all funds associated with a given asset managers, I get blank results. I can't figure out why this is the case so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should supply the query you are using. What you describe is the standard principle of 1-to-N relationships, so the flaw must lie within your query.

Comment: Possibly but there may be an even more fundamental flaw here. I should mention that the field SponsorID in the funds table is empty, meaning I did not populate it. Of course, if I populate it, then all works but if I have to populate it manually, then what is the purpose of creating relationships? I could just store everything in one table...I wish i could upload the file but it doesn't seem allowed

Comment: Simply creating a relationship will not populate another table. How could it? Is it up to the relationship to decide what funds a manager will have? No. Of course you will need to populate it manually. Do a bit of reading on outer joins (left/right) to find a way to retrieve managers that do not have corresponding funds, but other than that, you need a better understanding of the idea of a relational database. Good luck.

Comment: @parakmaikos ...my words ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bernardo, please read something about database creation and management. There are many good and free tutorials online.
The Tables cannot sniff magically which funds belongs to which manager: you have to tell them. And how do you do that? Exactly: by setting the managerID in teh funds table to the ID of the manager that should be connected to that funds. And THEN the relationship starts to have meaning: when you open a table of the managers you can also see, which funds are related (because access finds them, because you provided the connection...)

Comment: yeah i was missing one key piece. Use sub-forms top populate information! Thanks